# 500 Error on website which is quite random

Tags: coldfusion

we are running coldfusion 9 on centos OS. Recently we are having too much crash of the server, and 500 error like 504 gateway time out.

sometime i get the error

> Internal Server Error
>
> ```
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, root@localhost and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
> ```
>
> that may have caused the error.
>
> ```
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
>
> Apache/2.2.3 (CentOS) Server at www.mywebsite.com Port 80
> ```

I want to get notified when the my browser throw the 500 error, or till my issue is not solved, i would like to restart the server automatically

if this possible, how can i proceed ahead.

regards, need your advice very much as i am facing this issue now too much.

checked the logs also, sometimes i see [Broken Pipe] error being shown but not sure how to proceed

Here is the Update I just Checked the Log which shows on cfserver.log

i am not detecting something unusual:

can anyone point me in direction

```
>     1.0  Starting Macromedia JRun 4.0 (Build 108858), coldfusion server
> 2.0  01/19 04:42:58 warning Unable to open /opt/coldfusion9/runtime/lib/license.properties
> 3.0  01/19 04:42:59 info JRun Naming Service listening on *:2932
> 4.0  01/19 04:42:59 info No JDBC data sources have been configured for this server (see jrun-resources.xml)
> 5.0  01/19 04:42:59 info JRun Web Server listening on *:8500
> 6.0  01/19 04:42:59 info JRun Proxy Server listening on *:51011
> 7.0  01/19 04:42:59 info Deploying enterprise application "Adobe_ColdFusion_9" from: file:/opt/coldfusion9/
> 8.0  01/19 04:43:00 info Deploying web application "Adobe ColdFusion 9" from: file:/opt/coldfusion9/
> 9.0  01/19 04:43:00 error There is no web application configured to service your request
> 10.0     01/19 04:43:00 user NoWebappServlet: init
> 11.0     01/19 04:43:00 user FusionReactor: FusionReactor Rev. 3.5.1, Build: FusionReactor.78.14986
> 12.0     01/19 04:43:00 user FusionReactor: Initializing configuration
> 13.0     01/19 04:43:00 user FusionReactor: Loading configuration from /opt/fusionreactor/instance/default/conf/reactor.conf...
> 14.0     Jan 19, 2014 4:43:00 AM com.intergral.fusionreactor.core.u mb
> 15.0     INFO: Initialization failed: /opt/fusionreactor/instance/default/conf/reactor.conf (No such file or
> directory)
> 16.0     01/19 04:43:00 user FusionReactor Exception: /opt/fusionreactor/instance/default/conf/reactor.conf (No such file or
> directory)
> 17.0     java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/fusionreactor/instance/default/conf/reactor.conf (No such file or
> directory)
> 18.0     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
> 19.0     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
> 20.0     at com.intergral.fusionreactor.config.d.d(ConfigurationHandler.java:44)
> 21.0     at com.intergral.fusionreactor.core.u.vc(FusionReactor.java:533)
> 22.0     at com.intergral.fusionreactor.filter.FusionReactorFilter.init(FusionReactorFilter.java:640)
> 23.0     at jrun.servlet.FilterObject.init(FilterObject.java:63)
> 24.0     at jrun.servlet.FilterManager.loadFilter(FilterManager.java:220)
> 25.0     at jrun.servlet.FilterManager.init(FilterManager.java:158)
> 26.0     at jrun.servlet.FilterManager.create(FilterManager.java:75)
> 27.0     at jrun.servlet.WebApplicationService.start(WebApplicationService.java:230)
> 28.0     at jrun.ea.EnterpriseApplication.start(EnterpriseApplication.java:194)
> 29.0     at jrun.deployment.DeployerService.initModules(DeployerService.java:708)
> 30.0     at jrun.deployment.DeployerService.createWatchedDeployment(DeployerService.java:243)
> 31.0     at jrun.deployment.DeployerService.deploy(DeployerService.java:428)
> 32.0     at jrun.deployment.DeployerService.handleEvent(DeployerService.java:382)
> 33.0     at jrunx.kernel.JRunServiceDeployer.fireEvent(JRunServiceDeployer.java:710)
> 34.0     at jrunx.kernel.JRunServiceDeployer.deployServices(JRunServiceDeployer.java:111)
> 35.0     at jrunx.kernel.DeploymentService.loadServices(DeploymentService.java:46)
> 36.0     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> 37.0     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> 38.0     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
> 39.0     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
> 40.0     at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.StandardMBeanIntrospector.invokeM2(Unknown
> Source)
```

Answer (score 1):

A 500 error is just the generic HTTP response code ColdFusion sends if you have a runtime error in your code. The error you have posted is just the generic Apache error template, I think, which isn't any help.

You need to look at your exception logs to see what's errorring.

The log you show about is just your start-up log, and won't be representative of *ongoing* errors. It looks like FusionReactor is misconfigured, so is not starting up. However - as I said - this is a different issue from the one you're asking about here.

TBH, if you are asking questions @ this fundamental level, you perhaps should not be trying to troubleshoot this yourself, instead getting a consultant in for a day to sort it out.

Comment: Any consultant you can guide through, we have been facing this now very badly, and i checked the exception logs and figured out that pages through error and they are logged, so that could be the case in that purpose, but 504 error is not associated with these exception logs, that is somewhat related to the server

Comment: Hi Another thing, we do have stage server also, which is always online, only issues with the production server. Another error which pops up i found in the server.log file is: **Same Serial Number found on another ColdFusion server.The server may be out of compliance**

Comment: we have enabled the error logging, and few scheduled are also set up, if any error comes up on website, we do receive an email. In email two errors comes up: too many connections from ipaddress [same], sometimes it is blocked by PLS another ipaddress. Hope y questions are making sesnse